# How to get an Icon Component in react-native-paper without Button Component like in react-native-elements

Tags: react-native, icons, react-native-elements, react-native-paper

I'm using **react-native-paper** and I want to get an **Icon component** but without any link with Button Component. I went through [the doc](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/icons.html) and I didn't found an Icon Component. I want something similar than **react-native-elements** one

```
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'


<Icon
  name='g-translate'
  color='#00aced' />
```

So please help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 5):

you can use "react-native-vector-icons" library because the icon in react-native-paper is from react-native-vector-icons. 
here is code:

> `import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'; 
>   const myIcon = <Icon name="rocket" size={30} color="#900" />;`

Comment: But I wanted to use react-native-paper because it provides a very good way to set a custom icon than react-native-vector-icons itself

Comment: What do you want to custom?

Comment: react-native-paper gives the possibility to easily set a custom icon from image. For example
``` <Button icon={require('../assets/chameleon.jpg')}>
  Press me
</Button>```
But now I want to use Icon without ButtonComponent that's why I'm asking an Icon Component

Comment: Hi. Sorry i have some busy work. i think you have 2 ways. 1. Use Button without text and disabled props is true. 2. Use IconButton and set disabled props is true. way 2 is easy to use and work i think. Goodluck!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach would be to directly import the Icon component from the source directory of react-native-paper:

```js
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { Text } from 'react-native-paper'
import Icon from 'react-native-paper/src/components/Icon'

function Price() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>&euro; 2,100.58</Text>
      <Icon source="arrow-right" size={15} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Edit: With the latest version you can also directly import the Icon component.

```js
import { Icon } from 'react-native-paper'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Avtar.Icon. By default, it has some margin around the icon. You can create your own component by modifying the Avtar.Icon. Here is an example:

```
    const iconSize = 34
    const customAvtardimension = 0.6 * iconSize
    <Avatar.Icon
      size={iconSize}
      icon="bell-ring-outline"
      color={Colors.redA700}
      style={{
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        width: customAvtardimension,
        height: customAvtardimension,
      }}
    />
```